# How to migrate a file on Linux server?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ftp

I have renamed a shell script on my linux server and uploaded a new file through FTP tool like WinScp.

Now, I am trying to execute this file through Terminal but I am getting **Permission Denied** Error.

To fix this issue, I executed **touch** command but still have the same issue.
I am using the same user account to login into Terminal as well as upload the file.

Is this the permission issue like my user account hasn't access to upload the file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the file excutable. The `touch` command doesn't do that, the `chmod` command does:

```
chmod a+x some_new_file.sh
```

Or use your GUI to set the excutable permissions on the file.

Don't forget, if you're uploading a script, that you must transfer the file in TEXT mode and *not* in BINARY mode. Otherwise it'll fail at the next step (when you run it).

Comment: Thank you @roaima. Should I choose Text mode for all types of file like - XML, .pip, .php or only for shell scripts?

Comment: Hi roaima, can you please confirm about what is the difference between TEXT mode and ASCII mode transfer?

Answer (score 1):

To see the permissions on your file run:

```
ls -l yourfile
```

You should see output like:

```
$ ls -l newfile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ira ira 0 Dec 11 09:41 newfile
```

Where the "-rw-rw-r--." part is read/write/execute permissions for the user, group and everybody else. The 'ira ira' part is the user and then the group that the user belongs to.

From more info on **chown** and **chmod** see [this how-to article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/)